# Multiple bounding boxes around Object (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, non-maximum-suppression

I am new to ML, and OpenCV and was trying to perform object detection of a car using the pre-trained model on Coco Dataset, DNN. I am receiving multiple bounding boxes around the car.

The code and image are attached for reference.

```py
cap = cv2.imread(r'D:\car.jpg')

while True:
    (classIds, scores, bboxes) = model.detect(cap)
    for classId, score, bbox in zip(classIds, scores, bboxes):
        (x, y, w, h) = bbox
        className = classes[classId]

        if className == 'car':
            cv2.putText(cap, className, (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (200,0,50), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(cap, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (33, 191, 130),3)

    cv2.imshow('abc', cap)
    if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
        break
```

[image: Output image]

Comment: Look for "Non Maximal Suppression". It removes overlapping boxes

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while True` loop?

Comment: @Markus I couldn't perform the exit without that.

Comment: Non-Maxi**mum** Suppression but google will correct that

Comment: @Ayush Porwal. What if you move outside of the if/else condition in line 11?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I did that but it's not helping

Comment: Have you tried ready to use "non maximum suppression"-functions from the net as Jeru Luke suggests, like [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python)? Do you still have issues?

Comment: @Markus I did try NMS. It helped thanks.
The accuracy is low though. Can you please suggest something regarding the same? TIA

Comment: @Ayush Porwal: What do you mean by low accuracy?

Comment: @Markus If there are N cars in an image, around N/2 are detected.

Comment: @Ayush Porwal. What if you move outside of the for looping in line 11?

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes. I did actually after you informed it. The boundary box issue is resolved with the help of NMS. But I am unable to detect with good accuracy.

Comment: Can you post second image?

Comment: @toyotaSupra
   Markdown ![sample image](https://ibb.co/QQtNh66)

Comment: Notice. Using the same video that you posted previously, But no other videos..

Comment: @toyotaSupra Almost no other images. Is it because of the dimensions of the image?